# Is this design one of the standard design patterns?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have some C++ classes like this:

[image]

The class which controls replaying of messages is `ReplayController`.  By composition, it contains a `switch_controller` and a `cti_client_controller object`.  These objects are *specialisations* which know how to handle `switches` and `cti` clients respectively.

Is there a name for this structure?  Is it a design pattern?

Comment: Why don't you just store pointers to ReplaySubController in ReplayController and make an actual use of polimorphism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even the diagram looks familiar to

[image]

(source: wiki).

This looks like the [**Strategy pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).